# Extract number from desired position of div classes content, and sum them using jQuery and regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, count, numbers

I need to get the numbers from divs with specific classname and sum them. 
code example looks like this:

```
    <div class="refineItem plz3">38440&nbsp;(19)</div>
    <div class="refineItem plz3">38444&nbsp;(4)</div>
    <div class="refineItem plz3">31993&nbsp;(6)</div>
```

For example, i want here to get all the latest numbers 19,4,6 and then sum them (sum = 29).

Comment: what you have tried yet?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop over all the elements and `regex` to extract the number form the string.

See comments inline in the code:

```
var total = 0; // Initialize to zero

// For all the elements having refineItem class
$('.refineItem').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).text().match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1], 10) || 0; // Use zero when no matching number
});
$('#myInput').val(total); // Update the value of textbox
```

**Regex Explanation**

1. `/`: Delimiters of `regex`
2. `\(`: Matches literal `(`
3. `\)`: Matches literal `)`
4. `()`: Capturing group
5. `\d+`: Matches one or more digits

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5geu0wcf/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var count = 0;
$('.refineItem').each(function() {
    count += parseInt($(this).text().split("(")[1].split(")")[0]);
});
 alert(count);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkbvp264/)

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you can iterate over each div by using class name you have provided and also can get the text written inside the div and after that using the match function you can get the number from that text and convert it into number so that you can add that into a variable and get the output.

```
var total = 0;
$(".refineItem").each(function(){
total += Number(Number($(this).text().trim().match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1]));
});
```

Or

```
var total = 0;
$(".plz3").each(function(){
total += Number(Number($(this).text().trim().match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1]));
});
```

You can also check this example on JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/harshgupta69/pgugh65e/

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it clearer for other readers.